# How to check if this page in active page on opened tabs in php

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

In instagram while you opened and looking someone story it has a timeout until goes to next story, but when you changing browser tab it stops and when you back it goes from where you left page.
sorry for my bad English I hope you have got it.

So how can I do that in php, I want to stop a countdown when user leaves the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [an example how to keep your animations in sync when browser tab is changed](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/).

You could use the same approach to pause/resume your story timeout when current browser tab is in/active using HTML 5 visibility API like so:

```
var vis = (function(){
var stateKey, 
    eventKey, 
    keys = {
            hidden: "visibilitychange",
            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
};
for (stateKey in keys) {
    if (stateKey in document) {
        eventKey = keys[stateKey];
        break;
    }
}
return function(c) {
    if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
    return !document[stateKey];
}})();
```

Live preview on codepen: https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/sxgJl

Comment: Exactly what I want, tanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get when the user leaves

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // What to do when user leaves
});
```

And then this other to get when the user returns

```
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    // What to do when user comes back
});
```

Use it on `ready` because it will automatically trigger the `focus` function, and it can throw errors if the DOM isn't loaded yet. Also remember to prepare it to don't do anything you do on focus at first time, except it isn't a problem.